# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't start or install

Tags: installation, ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, hp-pavilion

I have an HP G4-1387 which has two graphics cards, an ATI 7450M and Intel HD3000.

I tried to install Ubuntu and run it from my USB stick, I get the usual black, console like screen showing a lot of things in an small resolution, then the screen adjust the resolution and then it is suppose to start Ubuntu or installation but instead I get a black screen forever. I think is related to a graphics card driver problem.

Any idea how to solve it? 
Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) should help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. get an ubuntu .iso image.
2. use any program to write the iso to your usb drive
3. reboot through your usb drive
4. you will get a screen having title ubuntu
5. select install on hard drive
6. follow the steps of installation
7. reboot, this time ubuntu on your bootloader.

Comment: I know how to install Ubuntu the problem is that I can't because I get a black screen before installation starts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. The screen was black because it has no bright at all by pressing the bright buttons you can see the screen.